# Generics - ClassCastException when extending Number

Tags: java, generics

I'm learning to work with generics, I can't understand why this is throwing an exception:

My 'GenericList' class:

```
package com.company.generics;

public class GenericList<T extends Number>{

    private T[] items = (T[]) new Object[10];
    private int count;

    public void add(T item){
        items[count++] = item;
    }

}
```

My main class:

```
package com.company;

import com.company.generics.GenericList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GenericList<Integer> g = new GenericList<>();

    }
}
```

Exception thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Number; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.Number; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.company.generics.GenericList.<init>(GenericList.java:4)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Comment: Because you can't do it. You can't cast `Number[]` to `Integer[]`, for example. You have to cast the array *element* everywhere required.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why "java.lang.ClassCastException: \[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to" error for Bounded type parameters and not for Formal Type parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58036163/why-java-lang-classcastexception-ljava-lang-object-cannot-be-cast-to-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `T` has an upper bound, the cast has an upper bound and is actually resolving to `Number` rather than `Object`.  You'll have to declare your array of that type instead of `Object`.

```
private T[] items = (T[]) new Number[10];
```

And according to *Effective Java,* you may have to add a `@SupressWarnings("unchecked")` to that assignment.  I didn't actually try it however.

Comment: A change from when?

Comment: Well I don't recall it working that way before.  I've always just used `Object[]` like the op has.  But I might be misremembering.

Comment: I feel like it's always resolved to the most specific type that can be inferred at compile time, though that doesn't come up too often.

Comment: Because the type is correctly declared as `T[]`, so you want to match it.  It's safer to do it that way because a `return items[x]` will return the correct type.  C.f. *Effective Java* by Joshua Bloch, Item 26 "Favor Generic Types."

Comment: I'm sure the OP's example has been reduced to the minimum for the sake of the question.  :)  I don't see any practical use for a class with only an `add()` method but no way to retrieve the values.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  The OP's code does compile, it throws a runtime error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought that as the Integer class extends the Number class I could write it in the way in which I did. A tutorial explaining generics showed the exact code compiling and running without throwing an error.

Comment: I've edited my answer to remove this part, but I don't remember needing to use `Number` instead of `Object` in these situations when generics were first introduced.  Of course, it's possible I don't remember correctly, and the author of your tutorial didn't check their code.